# is it safe to put an htaccess on 777 folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm wondering if it is safe and reliable to disable php from running by putting an htaccess on a folder which has 777 permission rights ?

Comment: 755 is a better setting for folders, and 644 for files.

Comment: Depends ENTIRELY on your server. if it's a shared server, then a .htaccess does nothing to prevent people from getting at the files via the server's filesystem - it's "everyone has access". All a .htaccess lockdown does is prevent access via the webserver.

Comment: If you are trying to build some kind of shared webhosting, keep also care of the users themselves (and their chrooted document root). Otherwise, one user could write a PHP script to delete the other folders .htaccess file and enable PHP for all other folders. And: FTP user is not the same as Webserver user.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I generally prefer 775 personally, but that's assuming other users in the group that owns the folder should be allowed to modify these files as well. Side note: `chmod g+s` on the directory helps with that as it makes any newly created files have the same group as the group that owns the directory.

Comment: @Powerlord True, and I prefer that setting also. I like to leave well enough alone (as it were). 777 should be restricted to (if I can say) "trusted" users and tucked away safely/neatly with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving permission 777 is never safe, it means you are giving access to everyone and everyone having all permission including delete.
First you should go for 644 (read-write by "owner")  if any issue go for 666.
However 755 must be your last resort.